# How to display related post by categories with next post of current post (don't latest post or random post)

Tags: thumbnails, wordpress, related-content

How to display related post by categories with next post of current post (don't latest post or random post). I'm use code related post for twentytwelve theme. but now, author in wentytwelve_entry_meta() is repeat.

pls help me :

```
<div id="related_posts">
    <?php
        $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
        if ($categories) {
            $category_ids = array();
            foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
                $id = $category->cat_ID;
            }
            global $wpdb;
            $query = "
                SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
                ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
                ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
                AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
                AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $category_ids[0]
                AND $wpdb->posts.id < $post->ID
                ORDER BY id DESC limit 3
           ";
           $my_query = $wpdb->get_results($query);
           if( $my_query) {
               echo '<h3>Related Posts</h3><ul>';
               foreach($my_query as $key => $post) {
               ?>
                   <li>
                        <div class="entry-header">
                            <div class="header-l">
                                 <h1 class="entry-title">
                                      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                </h1>
                                <p class="datetime">
                                    <?php twentytwelve_entry_meta(); ?>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                      </div>

                      <div class="entry-summary">
                          <?php
                              $str_content = wp_trim_words($post->post_content);
                              $str_content = str_replace('[', '<', $str_content);
                              $str_content = str_replace(']', '>', $str_content);
                              echo $str_content;
                          ?>
                     </div>
                </li>
           <?php
           }
           echo '</ul>';
       }
   }?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress customary is to use `WP_Query` class to fetch posts from DB, if you can modify your code to use `WP_Query` it would be easier.

[WP_Query Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

As you are using Custom Query to load your posts from DB, template tags like `the_permalink()`, `the_title_attribute()`, `the_title()` etc will not work properly that is the reason while theme function `twentytwelve_entry_meta()` fails.

As per codex reference [Displaying Posts Using a Custom Select Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query)

You should try something like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "
    SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
    ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
    ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $category_ids[0]
    AND $wpdb->posts.id < $post->ID
    ORDER BY id DESC limit 3";

$my_query = $wpdb->get_results($query);

if($my_query) {
    global $post;
    echo '<h3>Related Posts</h3><ul>';
    foreach($my_query as $key => $post) {
        //use setup postdata, it works only for variable named $post.

        setup_postdata($post); 
        //you can safely use template tags now.

        ?>
        <li>
            <div class="entry-header">
                <div class="header-l">
                    <h1 class="entry-title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h1>
                    <p class="datetime">
                        <?php twentytwelve_entry_meta(); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>


            <div class="entry-summary">
              <?php
                  $str_content = wp_trim_words($post->post_content);
                  $str_content = str_replace('[', '<', $str_content);
                  $str_content = str_replace(']', '>', $str_content);
                  echo $str_content;
              ?>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Other interesting post:

[What does setup_postdata ($post ) do?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99597/what-does-setup-postdata-post-do)